# SQL - select values from two tables but without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, and I want to select all columns from one table and plus one more column from another table, my code:

```
SELECT uc.*,ul.NAME FROM UC AS uc
inner JOIN UL AS ul
ON uc.PARTY_ID = ul.PARTY_ID WHERE PID = '33322';
```

This works but since in the table UL i have multiple value for PARTY_ID, for each of them i ve got extra row, can i somehow disable that, i only want to get one vale, any help?

UC table sample:

```
ID, PARTY_ID, PID
1, AAA, 33322
2, BBB, 33322
3, CCC, 2222222
```

UL table sample:

```
ID, PARTY_ID, NAME
1, AAA, HELLO
2, AAA, GOODBYE
3, BBB, LILA
2, BBB, MULI
```

The result should be:

```
ID, PARTY_ID, PID, NAME
1, AAA, 33322, HELLO
2, BBB, 33322, LILA
```

Comment: Define precisely how to select only one `ul.NAME` from all matched ones for definite `PARTY_ID`. Max? Min? else?

Comment: no criteria for that, it can be random, or the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several repeated  rows  you could try using DISTINCT

```
SELECT distinct uc.*,ul.NAME FROM UC AS uc
inner JOIN UL AS ul   ON uc.PARTY_ID = ul.PARTY_ID 
WHERE PID = '33322';
```

but based on your sample
if you want the result of all the names in a rows  you could use group_concat

```
SELECT uc.*, group_concat(ul.NAME)
FROM UC AS uc
inner JOIN UL AS ul   ON uc.PARTY_ID = ul.PARTY_ID 
WHERE PID = '33322'
group by uc.id;
```

otherwise if  the name value is not relevant you coul try using a fake aggregation function

```
SELECT uc.*, min(ul.NAME)
FROM UC AS uc
inner JOIN UL AS ul   ON uc.PARTY_ID = ul.PARTY_ID 
WHERE PID = '33322'
group by uc.id;
```

Comment: i tried this, but this wont work, still recive extra rows for each PARTY_ID

Comment: then try add  a clear data sample and the expcted  result al tabular text .

Comment: @ScaisEdge i did, please check

Comment: this works in way that i have no duplicate rows, but now in the column NAME i have all names as one string, can i just have one name?

Comment: @ttyttt  ..answer updated

Answer (score 0):

> it can be random – ttyttt

```sql
SELECT uc.column1, uc.column2, ... uc.columnN,
       ANY_VALUE(ul.NAME) ul_NAME 
FROM UC AS uc
INNER JOIN UL AS ul USING (PARTY_ID) 
WHERE PID = '33322'
GROUP BY uc.column1, uc.column2, ... uc.columnN;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d660ca882e19ee391db9c67c6df3705

Comment: ANY_VALUE is not recognized in my sql...

Comment: @ttyttt This is not correct. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value AFAIR it existed in 4th version... Fiddle added.

Comment: True but doesn't exist in mariadb perhaps OP has tagged incorrectly?

Comment: @P.Salmon Maybe. In this case he may use MIN()/MAX().

Answer (score 0):

You can use DISTINCT Function to return unique results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT uc.*,ul.NAME FROM UC AS uc
inner JOIN UL AS ul
ON uc.PARTY_ID = ul.PARTY_ID WHERE PID = '33322';
```

Comment: i tried this, but this wont work, still recive extra rows for each PARTY_ID

Comment: DISTINCT is **NOT** a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `sub-query` as well:

```
SELECT uc.*, sq.name
FROM UC as uc
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT party_id, MIN(name) as name
  FROM UL
  GROUP BY party_id
) as sq
ON uc.party_id=sq.party_id
WHERE uc.PID = '33322'
```

The sub query will return first name for each party_id